# Python requests efficiency

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using requests to get the final url of a link:

```
r = requests.get(link)
link = r.url
```

While this does work, it is VERY slow. I parse through a very large number of links, and this code makes my program significantly slower. Any link that has a redirection takes a good 5 seconds+ to get the final url. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Edit:
Am I using grequest incorrectly?

```
>>> r = grequests.get('http://muhlenberg.edu/main/campuslife/sye/index.html/')
>>> print r.url
http://muhlenberg.edu/main/campuslife/sye/index.html/
>>> r = requests.get('http://muhlenberg.edu/main/campuslife/sye/index.html/')
>>>> print r.url
http://www.muhlenberg.edu/errMsg/notFound.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if there are links which require 5 or more seconds to be accessed, there's not much to do about it. For your program as a whole, though, making the requests asynchronously with [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) might be a big improvement.

Comment: I can't seem to get grequests working, I edited my post with my attempt and comparison to using regular requests.